# Editing multiple TODO simultaneously -- priority and/or deadine

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Can anyone please steer me in the right direction to a function that will edit multiple TODO in one fell swoop.  Here are some examples:

- highlight a group of TODO that have deadlines and remove the dealines to make them undated.
- modify all priorites in a highlighted group -- e.g., #A to #D
- set deadlines by group and/or change deadlines by group -- e.g., move everything to a specific date, or set a specific date for each if they were undated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable [org-loop-over-headlines-in-active-region](http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-loop-over-headlines-in-active-region), when set to `t`, will allow to act on several headings at once.

You can highlight a region, and all headings in the region will be affected by the following commands: `org-schedule`, `org-deadline`, `org-todo`, `org-archive-subtree`, `org-archive-set-tag` and `org-archive-to-archive-sibling`

Changing priority is not supported.

Comment: Thank you very much -- I've been doing some experimenting with the options you've mentioned and I'll report back with the results after I've had a few days to figure everything out.

Comment: I had a few issues with org-deadline (i.e., Emacs freezing, and dates not changing), but I have not yet tracked down the root cause.  However, the built-in functions suggested by `Juancho` are a good starting point to begin writing my own modification to customize the organization to my personal needs.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: If you want to automate things further via elisp, the function `org-map-entries` is very useful. It loops through all headlines matching a specified criteria, and you just have to provide the code to run in each match.

Comment: Here is the one-fell-swoop change of org-deadlines written by Bruce Connor:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493745/org-deadline-change-all-in-selected-block-in-one-fell-swoop